# Remove the content of multiple folders with a bash script in Moba

Tags: bash, scripting, mobaxterm

I'm trying to delete all the files contained in multiple folders.

I'm trying to have a code working like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd path1                            rm -R *
cd path2                            rm -R *
....
cd pathN                            rm -R *
```

But it doesn't seems to work. It's possible to use the **cd** for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give multiple files/directories in rm command:

```
rm -rf path1 path2 path3 pathN
```

Please note, if you use `-rf` option, it will delete everything under the path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But it seems that it will delete the folder of the path not only the content of it

Comment: If you want to keep `path1`, and delete everything in it, use it like `rm -rf path1/* path2/* path3/* pathN/*`